# Help with the geometry figure

Tags: diagrams, metapost

Can someone help me with creating such a figure in metapost?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @Jubobs if only that were true.... :)

Comment: @cmhughes I guess the temptation to answer can be overwhelming, sometimes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing difficult in this:

```
beginfig(1);
r=2cm; % radius

% vertices of the equilateral triangle
z0=origin;
z1=(r*cosd(30),r*sind(30));
z2=z1 reflectedabout (origin,(1,0));

% incenter of the equilateral triangle is the barycenter
3z3=z0+z1+z2;
path innertriangle,innercircle;
innertriangle=z0--z1--z2--cycle;

% radius of the inner circle
s=x1-x3;
innercircle=fullcircle scaled 2s shifted z3;

draw innertriangle;
draw innertriangle rotated 90;
draw innertriangle rotated 180;
draw innertriangle rotated 270;
draw innercircle;
draw innercircle rotated 90;
draw innercircle rotated 180;
draw innercircle rotated 270;

draw fullcircle scaled 2r;
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Comment: You're the best man ! Thank you so much ! I own you a big vodka! ;p